# Table must receive foreign key?

Tags: database, normalization, rdbms

This is a simple question, but I think I always used the wrong way.

I have three tables called *Page* -> *Tag* -> *Attribute*. The Tag table receives the Page_Id (foreign key) and the Attribute table receives the Tag_Id (foreign key).

**The Attribute table must receive the Page_Id too?**

I never did this, but I saw a database SQL generator that does this, and so, I realized that this turns all the work easier, but this is the right way too?

---

**Edit with details of the tables:** The Page table contains HTML pages and some attributes like the content, the title, doctype and all other single elements of a html page.

The Tag table contains the HTML tags of a html page with informations like the tag (a, p, br, h1, title, etc.) and the entire tag.

The Attribute table contains all the attributes of a tag and is like a Map with key and value where each entry is an attribute and a value.

Page contains multiple tags (1:N) and tag contains multiple attributes (1:N). Each table contains a unique identification.

Comment: I think I have something relevant to add here, but I'd like to understand your table structure better before I jump in. Can you edit your question and include table structures and sample data, please?

Comment: @Catcall I edited my question with more details about the tables.

Comment: Thanks, but that doesn't help me. I'd rather see the table structures themselves (SQL DDL) including their primary keys and foreign keys--not a description of the table structures--before I jump in. A few rows of sample data would be helpful, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one of those "it depends" situations - you don't, *logically* need the value to be stored in `Attribute`, since you can derive this information by joining to `Tag`.

But, in some circumstances, it may be *useful* for you to be able to "jump" from `Attribute` to `Page` without having to join to `Tag`. In such a situation, you can include `Page_Id` in `Attribute`, but you should add additional constraints to ensure that it isn't inconsistent with the value stored in `Tag`.

---

You would enforce this consistency by having two keys declared in `Tag` - the usual key you define (e.g. `Tag_Id`), and also a superkey on `Tag_Id` and `Page_Id`. You would then declare a foreign key constraint in `Attribute` that includes *both* columns, and references this superkey. Whether you do that *instead* of the foreign key constraint on just `Tag_Id`, or in addition to it, can also be a matter of preference/style.

---

If it's likely that `Tag`s will change `Page`s, then you would normally declare the foreign key to the superkey as the one on which an `UPDATE CASCADE` occurs - in this way, if the `Page_Id` changes in the `Tag` table, that change will be automatically applied in the `Attribute` table.

Comment: I think you're mistaken. I don't think you can normalize the OPs structure to 5NF without having page_id as part of the key in the "last" table. But I'd be happy if you can show me where I went wrong in my answer.

Comment: @Catcall - I answered before the edit, and am only just reading it. I'm still not sure whether tags are unique on each page (so your initial diagram of table A would be incorrect to have tag 1 associated with both pages 1 & 2) - as I understand it, each attribute belongs to a single tag, and each tag belongs to a single page.

Comment: In simple HTML, tags aren't unique on each page. (I have many pages with <p> tags.) The <p> tags on a page can *use* different attributes of a *fixed set* of attributes. So on a single page I might have some <p> tags with no attributes, some that have "class" attributes, some that have "id" attributes, and so on. In simple HTML, attribute doesn't determine tag; most tags can have class attributes, id attributes, and so on. (I'm not entirely certain this is what the OP means. But I think it is.)

Comment: @Catcall - but the phrasing within the OPs question that the tags table includes both "the tag" and "the entire tag", implies to me, that there are two separate rows for "the 3rd `p` tag on page `x`" and "the 4th `p` tag on page `x`".

Comment: Yeah, I *think* I modeled that as far as the keys go. Imagine the first two rows of my sample data are for "the 3rd p tag on page x", and the second two are "the 4th p tag on page x".  If I'd included an "entire tag" attribute, it would have ended up in either Table_C or yet another table.  But that wouldn't have affected whether page_id ends up as part of the key in that "attribute" table, and *that's* what I was trying to focus on.

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary, and if you are strictly normalizing then the answer should be "page_id should not be on table Attribute". But it's often needed (for reporting or just speeding up some actions) to de-normalize tables, for example adding a field on a table that you could get by a simple query (like in your example).

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen your table structures, so I have to go on your description. That's always risky.

If your description means there's a 1:M relationship between pages and tags, and a 1:M relationship between tags and attributes, then sample data for the starting relation should look something like the table below. (The starting relation always contains all the attributes for all the tables.) I presume that

- page_id is supposed to identify a page,
- tag_id is supposed to identify a tag, and
- the attributes for a tag depend on which page that tag appears. (So there *isn't* a multi-valued dependency between tag and attribute.)

  ```
  Table_A
  page_id  page_name  tag_id  tag_name  attr_id
  --
  1        page1      1       tag1      attr1
  1        page1      1       tag1      attr2
  1        page1      2       tag2      attr1
  1        page1      2       tag2      attr3
  2        page2      1       tag1      attr1
  2        page2      1       tag1      attr2
  2        page2      2       tag2      attr1
  2        page2      2       tag2      attr2
  ```

We already know from your description that page_id -> page_name, and tag_id -> tag_name. (Unless you're trying to hurt yourself, page_name -> page_id and tag_name -> tag_id, too.)  So let's project new tables based on that knowledge.

```
Table_C
tag_id  tag_name
--
1       tag1
2       tag2

Table_B
page_id  page_name
--
1        page1
2        page2

Table_A
page_id  tag_id  attr_id
--
1        1       attr1
1        1       attr2
1        2       attr1
1        2       attr3
2        1       attr1
2        1       attr2
2        2       attr1
2        2       attr2
```

What functional, multi-valued, or join dependencies remain in Table_A? There are none. The only candidate key is {page_id, tag_id, attr_id}. I'm pretty sure all three of these tables are in at least 5NF.

So if you normalize your starting table, you end up with the page_id in the "last" table. (And, by the way, it's not really an attribute table any more, is it?)